# Power BI - Show only data that belongs to the required selection (And Logic)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table like this

```
Role            Skills       Resource
Data Analyst     R             A
Data Analyst     Python        A
Data Analyst     SQL           B
Business Analyst SQL           A
```

My Skills are on filter. I have multiple visuals on the dashboard.

And If I select SQL and Python then the results of both Data Analyst and Business Analysts are getting displayed in the visual.

But, I want it to display only the Data Analyst results because only Data Analyst has all the selected skills.

To achieve this, I think of creating a measure and putting it on visual level filter in each of the visual might help.

**Update :- If I select SQL here, I get 2 distinct resources on my card visual which is relevant to resources, but If I select SQL and Python - I get 0 Resources on my card visual which is relevant to resources and 1 role count which is relevant to roles on the Role measure.**

Kindly help me with creating that measure.

Comment: What should happen if Skill filter has no selection (in effect, it selects all skills)? If I understand your logic, all visuals then must be blank because no roles have all skills. If so, then your report will always be blank unless a user selects specific skills and the selected skill set has at least one role that meets it. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps someone will suggest a more elegant way to do it; I came up with the following ideas.

Create a measure (I'll call your table "Data"):

```
Has All Selected Skills
=
VAR 
   Selected_Skills = ALLSELECTED ( Data[Skills] )
VAR 
   Role_Skills = CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Skills] ), ALL ( Data[Skills] ) )
VAR 
   Missing_Skills = COUNTROWS ( EXCEPT ( Selected_Skills, Role_Skills ) )
RETURN
   IF ( NOT ( Missing_Skills ), 1 )
```

If the measure is placed in a visual against Roles, it'll produce the following results:

[image]

[image]

The way this code works:

- First, we store all selected skills in a variable "Selected_Skills";
- Second, we store all skills available for a role in a variable "Role_Skills". We must use ALL(Data[Skill]) to ignore the skill slicer selections;
- Third, since both variables above are tables, we can use EXCEPT function to find how they are different. Here, we tell DAX to find what records in Selected_Skills don't exist in Role_Skills. Store the result in a variable "Missing_Skills".
- Finally, if Missing_Skills is zero, it means that the role has all selected skills, and we flag it as 1 (although you might use True/False, etc).

The problem I see with this approach is that if Skill selector has no selection (shows "all skills"), then the formula might return blank for all roles, and all your visuals will be blank. Technically, it's correct - it's essentially saying that no roles have all skills. But if that's not the behavior you want, consider a slightly modified approach:

```
Missing Skills Count
=
VAR 
   Selected_Skills = ALLSELECTED ( Data[Skills] )
VAR 
   Role_Skills = CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Data[Skills] ), ALL ( Data[Skills] ) )
VAR 
   Missing_Skills = COUNTROWS ( EXCEPT ( Selected_Skills, Role_Skills ) )
RETURN
   Missing_Skills + 0
```

The formula uses the same logic, only returns the number of missing skills per role, instead of a true/false status. It will allow you to show a list of skills, sorted by the number of missing skills vs the selected skill set:

[image]

You can still use it to filter your visuals; the advantage is that it's never blank, even if all skills are selected:

[image]

It also gives you a capability to see what roles are the closest to meeting the requirement, even if none matches it perfectly; might be a desirable feature.

Final note: in all these reports, I have no subtotals and totals, assuming that they are not important. If you do need them, then the formulas might need to be modified to meet your requirements for the totals (depending on what you want to show there).

Comment: Thank you. But the only problem is I have a card visual in power bi, which gives me the count of resources but because it is not directed against roles, the visual level filter is not getting supported. Can you suggest a work around for that. Thanks again.

Comment: Card visual is essentially similar to the "total", so my final note is relevant here - what exactly would you like to see on the card?

Comment: Count of number of resources, so the hierarchy is Role, Resource and skills. let me add some sample data here and the output for that in a minute.

Comment: Updated the question now with the data.

Comment: @RADO Pretty slick!